# Getting binary input x86 tasm

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

How do I get input like in the first picture and use each bit for displaying different information. I've bit[1:0] which represents type of room, bit[8:2] for no. of seats available...so on, total of 16 bits. What I've done is instead of getting input, I declared room status as variable (room_status dw 0110111101111101b) everything works but I need to get room status as user input. How do i go about it?

[image]

```
data segment

nl          db 0ah, 0dh, '$'

w_board     db "White Board$"
b_board     db "Black_board$"
computer    db "Computer$"
projector   db "Projector"

room_status dw 0110111101111101b
room_type   db ?
num_seats   db ?
dep_ID      db ?
proj_comp   db ?
bw_board    db ?
PA_system   db ?

str1        db "Type of the room       : $"
str2        db "Number of seats        : $"
str3        db "Department                 : $"
str4        db "Overhead Projector/Computer: $"
str5        db "Black Board/White Board    : $"
str6        db "P.A. System                : $"

data ends

temp segment stack
db 200h dup(?)
temp ends

code segment
    assume cs:code, ds:data, ss:temp
start:  mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax
    ;your code starts here
    mov ax, room_status
    and ax, 0000000000000011b
    mov room_type, al

    mov ax, room_status
    and ax, 0000000011111100b
    ror ax, 2
    mov num_seats, al

    mov ax, room_status
    and ax, 0001111100000000b
    ror ax, 8
    mov dep_ID, al

    mov ax, room_status
    and ax, 0010000000000000b
    rol ax, 3
    mov proj_comp, al

    mov ax, room_status
    and ax, 0100000000000000b
    rol ax, 2
    mov bw_board, al

    mov ax, room_status
    and ax, 1000000000000000b
    ror ax, 1
    mov PA_system, al
    ;======================================
    ;type of room
    lea dx, str1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov dl, room_type
    add dl,30h
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h

    call newline
    ;=======================================
    ;no. of seats
    lea dx, str2
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 0 
    mov al, num_seats
    cmp ax, 10
    jb  bp1
    mov bl, 10d
    div bl

    mov bh, ah ;save remainder in bh register
    mov dl, al
    add dl, 30h
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    mov dl, bh ;second digit
    add dl,30h
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    jmp bp2

bp1:    
    mov dl, al
    add dl, 30h
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
bp2:
    ;department id
    call newline

    lea dx, str3
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, dep_ID
    cmp ax, 10d
    jb  bp3
    mov bl, 10d
    div bl

    mov bh, ah ;save remainder in bh register
    mov dl, al
    add dl, 30h
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    mov dl, bh ;second digit
    add dl,30h
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    jmp overhead_pj_comp
bp3:
    mov dl, al
    add dl, 30h
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h

overhead_pj_comp:
    call newline

    lea dx, str4
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov al, proj_comp
    cmp al, 0
    je  bb
    lea dx,computer
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    jmp boardT
pjet:
    lea dx,projector
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

boardT:
    call newline
    lea dx, str5
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

    mov al, bw_board
    cmp al, 0
    je  bb
    lea dx,w_board
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    jmp paSystem
bb:
    lea dx,b_board
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

paSystem:
    call newline
    lea dx, str6
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

    mov dl,al
    add dl,30h
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

done:
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
newline proc
    lea dx, nl
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    ret
newline endp

code ends
end start
```

This is the output of my program without user input
[image: This is the output of my program without user input]

Comment: Find an interrupt function that lets you read a string. Then parse the string that has been read.

Comment: For each digit, with `reg='0'` in some register, `cmp reg, digit` / `adc bx,bx` would shift a 0 or 1 into the bottom of a total in BX.  (where `digit` is a register or addressing mode).  You could even do that with `scasb` to do `al - [es:di]`

Comment: Of course, many people would find it easier to type in hex to represent a bit pattern.  base 2 with one symbol per bit is not an efficient format for ASCII, or easy for humans to deal with for more than a few bits.